# Accessing Images in media/ folder In Django

Tags: django, database, file

I'm currently learning about how images are stored in Django. To my understanding, Django stores all the images you upload in in a subdirectory of your site's media/ folder. My question is, let's say I create a website to upload images, where each image corresponds to a unique title (I will define this in my models.py file), like this:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Then, given the unique title of an image, how can I find the image in the media/ folder that corresponds to it? Are there any websites/sections in the Django documentation that explain this? I've tried searching for some, but haven't been able to find any.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.conf import settings
img_path = "your_server_address" + settings.MEDIA_URL + unique_img
```

In case you are using localhost, this is how u can access the image. Here **unique_path_to_image** is the path that is stored in database and **media_url_folder_name** is what you provide in **settings.py** file.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/media_url_folder_name/unique_path_to_image